# jquery serializeArray() wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to submit a form from a Wordpress Page to a php script that resides in the same directory as index.php using custom html option on the page to generate the form and using jQuery serializeArray() to send the data to the php script.

In console, when I submit `jQuery("#formID").serializeArray();` it returns an object which stores the name and value of each of the inputs.

However, when I use `jQuery("resultDiv").load("phpScript.php", jQuery("#formID").serializeArray());` the PHP `$_POST` variable is empty.

I've used this method in the past and it has worked. For some reason, it's not working in this case. Anyone else have this issue? Here's what the script looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//need to validate the form
jQuery("#sendForm").click(function() {
  var email = jQuery("#sub_email").val();
  var email2 = jQuery("#sub_verify_email").val();
  var type_reseller = jQuery("#sub_type").val();
  var province = jQuery("#sub_prov").val();
  var country_from = jQuery("#sub_country").val();
  var password = jQuery("#password").val();
  var pw_verify = jQuery("#pw_verify").val();

  if ( (email!=email2) || (email=="") )

  {
    alert("Email addresses do not match. Please re-enter.");
    jQuery("#sub_email").focus();
    jQuery("#sub_email").select();
  }


  else
  {

    if (type_reseller=="")
    {
      alert("Please enter a Reseller Type");
    }

    else
    {
      if  (province=="--")
      {
        alert("Please select a Province or State");
      }
      else
      {
        if  (country_from == "")
        {
          alert("Please select which country you are from");
          jQuery("#sub_country").focus();
          jQuery("#sub_country").select();
        }

        else
        {
          if  ((password!=pw_verify) || (password==""))
          {
            alert("Your Password entry does not match. Please re-enter");
            jQuery("#password").focus();
            jQuery("#password").select();
          }

          else
          {
            jQuery("#submitResult").html("<h2>Sending Form...</h2>");
            //submit the form to the database
            jQuery("#submitResult").load("../subscribeSubmit.php", jQuery("#Subscribe").serializeArray());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
//-->

//need to submit the form using ajax


</script>
```

Console entry of `JSON.stringify(jQuery("#Subscribe").serializeArray())` produces this output...

```
   "[{"name":"sub_conf","value":"Yes"},{"name":"sub_conf2","value":"Yes"},{"name":"sub_type","value":"Service Provider"},{"name":"sub_firstname","value":"hello"},{"name":"sub_lastname","value":"world"},{"name":"sub_company","value":"anycompany"},{"name":"sub_city","value":"anycity"},{"name":"sub_prov","value":"ON"},{"name":"sub_country","value":"Canada"},{"name":"sub_country","value":""},{"name":"sub_email","value":"anyone@anyplace.com"},{"name":"sub_verify_email","value":"anyone@anyplace.com"},{"name":"password","value":"hello"},{"name":"pw_verify","value":"hello"},{"name":"nl_version","value":"H"},{"name":"sub_comments","value":"this is a comment"},{"name":"form_submitted","value":"TRUE"}]"
```

When I used `print_r($_POST)` on the destination script to see what the script was receiving it returned `Array() (empty array)`.

The network response looks like this:

```
General:
Request URL:http://example.com/subscribeSubmit.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:222.222.222.222:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Header:
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 25 Jul 2017 18:04:51 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.7
X-Powered-By:PleskLin

Request Headers
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:pum-7361=true
Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/subscribe/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Two things: first, you should update the question with a better formatted version of the data produced by `jQuery("#Subscribe").serializeArray()`; the console output you provided is not clear what the data structure really is (try serializing to JSON). Second, check the Console network tab, to see what data is getting sent in the request.

Comment: @wmorrell I formatted the `console.log` output for you (that was more time consuming than I expected).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: use [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead of [`jQuery.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

---

I think the problem is the serialized data is not in the form that the `load` function is expecting. The request is therefore not sending any data (note the line `Content-Length:0` in the request headers). The [documentation for `load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does not say much about the format of data passed in until the end. The relevant section reads:

```
$( "#objectID" ).load( "test.php", { "choices[]": [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```

A better section of the documentation is the page for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The section there under **Sending Data to the Server** reads:

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`, or an object of the form `{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}`. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) before it is sent.

Note that your data is in the form `[{name: 'key1', value: 'value1'}]` instead of the form `{key1: 'value1'}`. You could re-map the array of values into an object of the proper form, but it seems much simpler to use the direct method of `serialize()` to get a `key1=value1` string.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem... the ID of the form was cleared when I replaced it with 'Submitting Form', so therefore, there was no form data to send... I removed that line and everything worked fine.